# Triplicates in R

Tags: r

I have a set of 80 samples, with 2 variables, each measured as triplicate:

```
sample  var1a    var1b    var1c    var2a    var2b    var2c
1      -169.784 -155.414 -146.555 -175.295 -159.534 -132.511
2      -180.577 -180.792 -178.192 -177.294 -171.809 -166.147
3      -178.605 -184.183 -177.672 -167.321 -168.572 -165.335
```

and so on. How do I apply functions like mean, sd, se etc. for each row for var1 and var2? Also, the dataset contains NAs. Thanks for bothering with such basic questions

Comment: You want mean sd etc for each row (sample 1, 2 and so on) for `var1a` `var1b` `var1c`  and another sd mean for each row (sample 1, 2 and so on) for `var2a` `var2b` and `var2c` together? in fact, for means, you want 6 means each one for each row and for all `var1` and `var2`?

Answer (score 0):

What is your expected result when there are NAs? `apply(df[-1], 1, mean)` (or whatever function) will work, but it would give NA as a result for the row. If you can replace NA with 0 then you could  do `df[is.na(df)] <- 0` first, and then the apply function in order to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to reshape your data set. Another one might be just apply a function over rows of a subset of the data frame.
So, for `var2X` you have:

```
apply(dat[5:7], 1, function(x){m <- mean(x); s <- sd(x); da <-c(m, s) })
           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,] -155.78000 -171.750000 -167.076000
[2,]   21.63763    5.573734    1.632348
```

and for `var1X`:

```
apply(dat[2:4], 1, function(x){m <- mean(x); s <- sd(x); da <-c(m, s) })
           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,] -157.25100 -179.853667 -180.153333
[2,]   11.72295    1.443055    3.520835
```